# Reduce number of for loops in method

Tags: java, loops, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm trying to reduce the number of for loops in this method, but I'm not sure how to do that while still keeping the logic in tact and not moving to another method. I want to do this for the sake of reducing the [McCabe Cycolmatic Complexity](http://docs.klocwork.com/Insight-10.0/McCabe_Cyclomatic_Complexity), which increases with each loop by 1. So I'd like to reduce the method by 1.

```
  private void method(int page)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LINES_PER_PAGE; i++)
        {
            nextLine[i] = null;
        }
        try
        {
            Scanner temp = new Scanner(fileToPrint);
            for (int i = 0; i < page - 1; i++)
            {
                skipAPage(temp);
            }
            for (int i = 0; (i < LINES_PER_PAGE) && (temp.hasNext()); i++)
            {
                nextLine[i] = expandTabs(temp.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason to refactor this code, it's as readable as it gets. But I would advise always leaving white space before and after any conditional or loop statements, it may add +2 more lines, but it is lot easier on the eyes.

Comment: Why can't you move part of the code to other method? You could at least extract first part into some `clearLines(nextLine, LINES_PER_PAGE)` which is quite logical thing to do in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES_PER_PAGE; i++) {
        nextLine[i] = null;
    }
```

This is completely unnecessary, because default value for any object is `null` in java.

In the rest of two loops, you are calling two different methods and your second loop also depends on the argument, so I am not sure they can be merged into one loop.

---

As it appears that `nextLine` is declared outside the method,  I would suggest you to use `List<Sometype>` and add the elements into it, coming from `expandTabs(temp.nextLine());`, every time you enter the method clear the list `list.clear()`.

---

Try this code. Use the appropriate type for declaring the `List<String>`. You can access the element from the `List` using `myList.get(index)` method.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

private void method(int page) {
  try {
    myList.clear();            // Clear the list.
    Scanner temp = new Scanner(fileToPrint);
    for (int i = 0; i < page - 1; i++) {
      skipAPage(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; (i < LINES_PER_PAGE) && (temp.hasNext()); i++) {
      myList.add(expandTabs(temp.nextLine()));    // Add the elements to the list.
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't true - nextLine is declared outside the method, and could therefore be populated before this method.  The for loop isn't guaranteed to fully populate nextLine, and therefore nulling out the elements is reasonable.

Comment: @Sbodd your observation seems to be correct. I would suggest to use List in that case, instead of an array. Then he won't need to loop.

Comment: @YoungHobbit could you show me what this would look like for this method? I haven't worked with list. not sure how to clear the lines with something like this: `List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( expandTabs(temp.nextLine()) ));`

Comment: @CarloOtto what is return type of `expandTabs(temp.nextLine())` and type of `nextLine[]`.

Comment: @YoungHobbit both are String. (expandTabs is `return temp.toString();`

Comment: @CarloOtto Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to skip the `skipAPage` step as I assume another loop in there:

```
        Scanner temp = new Scanner(fileToPrint);
        int linesToSkip = page * LINES_PER_PAGE;
        int i = 0;
        while ( temp.hasNext() ) {

             if ( i >= linesToSkip && i < linesToSkip  + LINES_PER_PAGE)
                  nextLine[i] = expandTabs(temp.nextLine());
             else
                  temp.nextLine();
             i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < LINES_PER_PAGE; i++)
    {
        nextLine[i] = null;
    }
```

with a call to [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Or just skip it entirely -- by default, an array of `Object`s is initialized to contain nothing but `null`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes what if `method()` were to be called twice?